# ((char) 257) prints 1 in C?

Tags: c, char-pointer

I am vastly confused. I'm having a headache.
I'm new to C.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i = 257;
int *iPtr = &i;    

printf("val 1: %d \t val 2: %d \n\n",*( (char*)iPtr ), *( (char*)iPtr+1) );

int iptr_alias = iPtr;
int and_val = iptr_alias & 255;

printf("Value of iPtr (aka address of i): %d   \n\n", iPtr);
printf("Value at location pointed to by iPtr using %%c: %c \n\n",*iPtr); //gives weird character


int f = 257;
int *fptr = &f;


printf("char starred fptr: %d \t charred 257: %d \n\n",*((char*)fptr), ((char)257) );
// i know the above is obvious. 
system("PAUSE");
}
```

My questions:

**1. Apparently `*( (char*) iPtr )` = `257 & 255` = 1 (bitwise and operation).
And `(char)*iPtr` is the same also** . But it doesn't print `1` if i use `%c` modifier. Why?

**2. And why `*( (char*) iPtr+1 )` = 1 ??**

I'm so confused with all this (which i wrote myself to clear confusion, but it worked otherwise..)

`((char)257)` gives `1` using `%d` or %o or %x for that matter. `%c` gives some weird ASCII character

I mean, when i do `printf(" %c ", 257)` , then i don't get `1`, instead, I get a weird ASCII character. Why?

In the actual problem, I was supposed to determine what would be printed as `val 1` and `val 2`.

I maybe overlooking anything stupidly simple, but i'm really feeling confused and tired about this mess.
Please help.

Comment: Are you asking why you get an ascii character with `%c`? Do you understand the difference between `%c` and `%d`?

Comment: printf("%c", 32) shows the ascii character. take a look at the ascii table, so you see what characters have which number. %i, %d etc format the values as a string, and then print the number.

Comment: no, i'm confused as to why `printf("%d", ((char)257) )` gives `1` whereas `printf("%d",257)` gives 257. Now obviously `(char)` is changing things, and now as i understand, ((char)257) (thanks to Joachim Pileborg) gives 1 because `Remember that a char is only 8 bits, and can therefore represent number from 0 to 255. When you print 257 it rolls over and becomes 1 (256 would be zero).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a `char` is only 8 bits, and can therefore represent number from 0 to 255. When you print `257` it rolls over and becomes 1 (`256` would be zero).

As for why why `257` (i.e. `1`) becomes a weird character, I direct you to an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

**Edit:** About `signed` versus `unsigned`

In this case, your `char` type is `unsigned`. If it were `signed` then the rollover would have happen at `127` (but due to how signed/unsigned works it would have roll over to `-128` and `129` would roll over to `-127`).

Comment: in this case `char` is unsigned. That's not always true.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg
i'm still confused about `*( (char*) iPtr+1 ) = 1`
wouldn't it be 2?

Comment: @TonyK That is _undefined behavior_, see my modified answer.

Comment: @TonyK, I don't really think that's undefined behavior, I've been told that conversions to/from `char*` are actually well defined. The reason you get `1` can be found in my answer.

Comment: Re your Edit 2, `*((char*)iPtr + 1)` is only undefined behaviour if `sizeof(int) == 1` (but then `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, so `(char)257` would yield 257). If `sizeof(int) > 1`, that gives you the second-lowest-addressed byte of the `int i;`, which in little-endian systems is 1, in big-endian systems would be 0 (like the lowest-addressed byte you'd get from `*((char*)iPtr)`).

Answer (score 1):

The integer 257 is also 0x101 in hex. On a little-endian machine with 32-bit integers the individual bytes will be 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00.